# How to add event listener for selectors whose element will have the class/id added later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of elements that I'd like to use as Bootstrap "collapse" widgets but the element Id's are dynamic.  So far I haven't been able to get them to work because their id's are added later - specifically the ID of the target "panel" to be opened/closed.  Code example:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="panel-collapse collapse in panel-body">

        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="panel-collapse collapse panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="panel-collapse collapse panel-body">

        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the bit of JavaScript which demonstrates how adding the ID dynamically does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panel-heading > .panel-title > a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
        var targetId = $(this).attr('href');

        $(this).closest('.panel-heading').next().attr('id',targetId);
        console.log(targetId);
    });
});
```

My gut tells me this has to do with how the events are registered to begin with, but I'm unsure how to even being fixing this.  What needs to be done?

Comment: I would assume that your problem is that the Bootstrap accordion plugin is initialized before you add those IDs and it looks for the counterparts for the toggles at that very moment (when the IDs are still blank) and not when to toggles are clicked later on. Thus move the initialization to after your script.

Comment: Piece at OP appears to return each `id` . If possible, describe issue ? See http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9mWjU/ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things. First, when adding or changing IDs, you'll want to use the `prop()` method not `attr()`. Second, you're adding the value of the `href` attribute as an ID, but that includes a hashtag at the beginning, which is not a valid ID. You'll want to strip that out before adding it as the new ID. Lastly, this isn't 100% necessary, but for clarity you should specify the element in the `next()` function.

Your code would be thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panel-heading > .panel-title > a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
        var targetId = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');

        $(this).closest('.panel-heading').next('.panel-body').prop('id',targetId);
        console.log(targetId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, just curious, but why exactly are the IDs added in this way? Is this code being generated by a server side script or is it something you can't change (in order to add the IDs in that scripts output)?